# ActiveRecord scope based on number of foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, arel

Given the canonical example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I would like to return a scope (i.e. `ActiveRecord::Relation`) of all the Posts that have X or fewer Comments; using either using [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) or something else if it solves my problem.

**Pseudocode:**

```
scope :quiet, lambda { |n| where(comments: { maximum: n }) }
```

I am aware that this can be done in Ruby with a simple `Enumerable#select`. It is preferable to be calculated on the database as in actuality there can only ever be one Model that satisfies the predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this..

```
Post.joins(:comments).group("posts.id HAVING count(comments.id) > 0")
```

Its not quite fully arel, but it will certainly work

Comment: Having is what I was looking for! The full arel (`.group(...).having(...)` code is extremely verbose offering little  extra benefit.

Answer (score 1):

what about this scope:

```
scope :quiet, ->(n) { where("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE post_id = `posts`.id) < ?", n) }
```

It will be done all database side. It is not using join, so you can actually update those post records if needed